# Selectize Refresh items dynamically with custom rendering

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

If you have created custom render functionality on your selectize dropdown, is it possible to refresh the dropdown items dynamically using ajax? I can do one or the other, but when I combine both parts of the functionality, the selectize dropdown items do not re-render.

I have used the callback function to set the new list of options.

The selectize control is initialized with the following javascript code when the page loads.

```js
var $select = $(item).selectize({
  create: false,
  sortField: 'text',
  selectOnTab: true,
  valueField: 'id',
  labelField: 'text',
  searchFields: ['text'],
  render: {
    item: function(selectItem, escape) {
      var splitAt = selectItem.text.indexOf(';');
      var label;
      var caption = '';
      if (splitAt > 0) {
        label = selectItem.text.substring(0, splitAt);
        caption = selectItem.text.substring(splitAt + 1);
      } else {
        label = selectItem.text;
      }

      return '<div>' +
        (label ? '<span class="text">' + escape(label) + '</span>' : '') +
        (caption ? '<span class="description">' + escape(caption) + '</span>' : '') +
        '</div>';
    },
    option: function(selectItem, escape) {
      var splitAt = selectItem.text.indexOf(';');
      var label;
      var caption = '';
      if (splitAt > 0) {
        label = selectItem.text.substring(0, splitAt);
        caption = selectItem.text.substring(splitAt + 1);
      } else {
        label = selectItem.text;
      }

      return '<div>' +
        '<span class="label">' + escape(label) + '</span>' +
        (caption ? '<span class="caption">' + escape(caption) + '</span>' : '') +
        '</div>';
    }
  }
});
```

I then have an ajax method that requests the latest drop down options and attempts to update the selectize control:

```js
var refreshSuppliers = function() {
    $.getJSON('url/suppliers', function(results) {
      if (results) {
        var selectOptions = [];
        for (var index = 0, length = results.length; index < length; index++) {
          var item = results[index];
          selectOptions.push({
            text: item.Option,
            value: item.Id.toString()
          });
        }

        var selectize = $("#Supplier")[0].selectize;
        selectize.clear();
        selectize.clearOptions();
        selectize.load(function(callback) {
          callback(selectOptions);
        });
      }
    })
```

Once the method runs, the dropdown on the web page is empty. If I remove all the custom rendering and treat as a simple selectize drop down, the ajax call to update the drop down works.

Is there a way for these two features to work together?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in the selectize.js library where the rendered output is not being cleared from the renderCache when you call clearOptions(). I was able to get this to work by clearing the cache manually:

```
selectize.clearOptions();
selectize.renderCache = {};
selectize.load(function(callback) {
    callback(selectOptions);
 });
```

There is an open issue on github for this:
https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/issues/260

Comment: I'm using 2 functions to remove all items before adding new ones, as it showed in the original question:
`selectize.clear(); selectize.clearOptions();`
Calling `clearOptions()` only didn't help. It was leaving a selected value.
Though documentation says
https://selectize.dev/docs.html
" **clearOptions(silent)** - Removes all options from the control, and resets/clears all selected items. ".
It doesn't do clear()'s job.

Comment: ```selectize.renderCache = {};``` works for me